# How can I create a django url specific to a user?

Tags: django, url, prefix

I am interested in making my urls customised for each user, something like 
`username.mysite.com/home` but I am not sure how to do this with django.

I am also curious if this might work in development (so as to have `username.localhost:8000/home`) or not.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try django.site framework

Comment: Found this [djangosnippets](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2062/) may help you

Comment: @bhushya The sites framework is for a rather different use-case, but it is very interesting and it might come in handy someday, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, Raja Simon, a middleware is probably going to be the way to go. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way as well. What you can do is have Middleware that gets the url, parses the subdomain and then renders a user profile page.

This is assuming you are using a custom profile page and not the default profile page.

```
#in yourapp.middleware
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import logging
import yourapp.views as yourappviews
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class AccountMiddleware(object):

def process_request(self, request):
    path = request.META['PATH_INFO']
    domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    pieces = domain.split('.')
    username = pieces[0]
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if path in ["/home","/home/"]:
            return yourappviews.user_profile(request, user.id)

#In yourapp.views.py

def user_profile(request,id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, "user_profile.html", {"user": user})

#In settings.py

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #... other imports here
    'yourapp.middleware.AccountMiddleware'
)
```

Comment: Something like in this tutorial -- https://www.wellfireinteractive.com/blog/multi-tennancy-in-django-using-subdomains/ ? Or do you have a better suggestion ?

Comment: A little easier. Let me write it quickly in code for you.

Comment: Oh, I understand, thanks for the update. Would the fact that I am using django-rest-framework change anything in the behaviour (except for the fact that the view will be a drf view) ?

Comment: Nope, since the render is called already, the result is sent back regardless of the response type.

Comment: And what should I change in my urls.py file ?

Comment: Don't have to change anything in urls.py if you've set up the Middleware correctly. The middleware intercepts the request and renders the result of the view.